# Node CLI template tool

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, template-engine, mustache

I want to use the following workflow in a Node project.

my-template.html: `<h1>{{header}}</h1>`

my-data.json: `{"header": "It works!"}`

`$ some-cli-tool my-data.json my-template
<h1>It works!</h1>`

What "some-cli-tool" am I looking for here? The Mustache CLI tool comes pretty close, but can't <del>handle nested data and loops</del> give me the current index of items in loops. I can't seem to figure out how to make the other tools I've stumbled upon to work according to the logic above (nunjucks, handlebars, etc).

Comment: As I know, mustache-cli can handle nested data and loops. https://github.com/quantumew/mustache-cli/tree/master/examples

Comment: Stupid me. Thank you!

Comment: Coming to think of it, Mustache still won't do. I need to access the current index of the loop item...

Comment: should you just index the items in your data set? it's because a template engine isn't supposed to handle much process.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to settle with that.